Google Calendar API is not working on Flutter web app
I have a Flutter app that I have added a calendar to and I want to add calendar events to the  user's web Google calendar. I am using the Google Calendar API to do this.
When I run the code and try to add an event to the calendar, nothing happens. As I go through the debugger, I don't get any errors.
Here is the code:
class CalendarClient {
  static const _scopes = [CalendarApi.calendarScope];
    
  insert(title, eventDate, startTime, endTime) {
    var clientID;

    if (kIsWeb) {
      clientID = ClientId("<my client ID here>.apps.googleusercontent.com","");
    } else {
      /// Android
      clientID = ClientId("<my client ID here>.apps.googleusercontent.com","");
    }

    clientViaUserConsent(clientID, _scopes, prompt).then((AuthClient client) {
      var calendar = CalendarApi(client);
      calendar.calendarList
          .list()
          .then((value) => debugPrint("VAL________$value"));

      String calendarId = "primary";
      Event event = Event(); // Create object of event

      event.summary = title;

      EventDateTime start = EventDateTime();
      start.dateTime = startTime;
      start.timeZone = "GMT+05:00";
      event.start = start;

      EventDateTime end = EventDateTime();
      end.timeZone = "GMT+05:00";
      end.dateTime = endTime;
      event.end = end;
      try {
        calendar.events.insert(event, calendarId).then((value) {
          debugPrint("ADDEDDD_________________${value.status}");
          if (value.status == "confirmed") {
            log('Event added in google calendar');
          } else {
            log("Unable to add event in google calendar");
          }
        });
      } catch (e) {
        log('Error creating event $e');
      }
    });
  }

  void prompt(String url) async {
    debugPrint("Please go to the following URL and grant access:");
    debugPrint("  => $url");
    debugPrint("");

    if (await canLaunchUrl(url as Uri)) {
      await launchUrl(url as Uri);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}

I have tried running it on both the chrome browser and on an Android device and neither works. It never asks me for access and in the debugger I don't get past this line:
clientViaUserConsent(clientID, _scopes, prompt).then((AuthClient client) {
I have put break points on the line right after this line and it never gets there but yet there are no errors.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help

Could you use myFunc().then(processValue).catchError(handleError); to catch error. CORS issue maybe.

Thank you for your comment. I tried it but it does not throw an error. After executing the  code, clientViaUserConsent, it pauses like it is waiting for some input but there is no window displayed.
